# How do I compare registry versions in WiX?

Tags: wix

In my wix installer, I want to check for a version of ESRI ArcMap which I can find by:

```
<Property Id="ARC10INSTALLED">
    <RegistrySearch Id="Arc10Search" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\ESRI\ArcGIS" Name="RealVersion" Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

I want starts with 10 and I've tried accomplishing it by using this condition:

```
<Condition Message="ArcGIS Desktop 10 or 10.1 must be installed"><![CDATA[ARC10INSTALLED AND ARC10INSTALLED >= "10.0.0"]]></Condition>
```

But that doesn't seem to work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The value returned by the [RegistrySearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm) element depends on the `@Type` attribute value, as well as on the data type of that value in the registry. Hence, in case you specify `raw` as a value of `Type` attribute, the result you'll get will most likely contain a certain prefix. For instance, if it's `REG_BINARY` you'll get the value prefixed with `#`. You should consider this in the operations of comparison.

As for the string comparison in particular, I would use the substring operators [supported by the MSI condition syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012.aspx). It supports 'starts with', 'ends with' and 'contains', which looks like the best way to identify your value `10.` somewhere in the value you receive in ARC10INSTALLED property.

Comment: The 'starts with' is exactly what worked. Thanks! And just to document what I used: <![CDATA[ARC10INSTALLED AND ARC10INSTALLED << "10"]]>