# How to configure .wxs file to to detect latest version of IE when writing to the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION RegistryKey?

Tags: wix

I have a .wxs file with a component

```
<Component Id="IE_BROWSER_EMULATION_REGISTRY" Guid="*">
     <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION">
          <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="SDLTradosStudio.exe" Value="9999" KeyPath="yes"/>
     </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

I know the end users will be using Windows 7 and will most likely have at least IE 9 installed on their computer. But I would really like to set the Value to the latest version of IE installed on the user's machine.  I am using the WiX Edit tool to build the .msi.  How can I detect the latest version of IE installed on the user's machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE Version is store in the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\svcVersion

Use the following code to get the Registry key value to a property

```
<Property Id="IEVERSION">
    <RegistrySearch Id="IEVer"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer"
             Name="svcVersion"
                    Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

Once you have the IE Version in a property you can use a condition to check it.

Example :

```
<![CDATA[IEVersion >= 9]]>
```

Comment: Now that I finally got to this a year later, here are some comments.  First, you need to remove the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\" from the "Key" attribute because that is communicated by the HKLM value in the "Root" attribute.  The question and answer at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245152/how-do-i-compare-registry-versions-in-wix give good information about how to actually compare the version number.  The value returned from RegistrySearch, in this case, is actually a string, not a number.